# android LinearLayout is hidden when FloatingActionsMenu is implemented

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Sorry for bad English. I've created an app interface material design with Toolbar,TabHost everything works fine. Then I wanted to add FloatingActionsMenu in a tab. so I used: http://com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu library. when I use FloatingActionsMenu other Contain of the tab is now disappeared. Here is my full xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        fab:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:showDividers="none"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    <!--The Other Contain in Tab one Container-->
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="This is Tab One Container"
                            android:id="@+id/textView"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_frame_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/white_overlay">
                        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                            android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/accent"
                            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/accent_dark"
                            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
                            fab:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="false"
                            fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
                            fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">
                        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/fab_event"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
                            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_dark"
                            fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/white"
                            fab:fab_icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                            fab:fab_size="mini"
                            fab:fab_title="Emails" />
                    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/gray">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="This is Tab Two Container"
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

`

Thanks in advance. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably mean that the FloatingMenu is disappearing on switching tabs
If that is what you are asking for then that is because of using the floating button inside tabs not for the tabs layout all

simply for not confusing yourself with the code create an app with a basic activity that means it already has a floating button like this temple in the Android Studio

[image]

and replace the FloatingButton with the FloatingMenu
and put you tabs content in the content_main.xml
that is the form in which the FloatingButton in all layouts of tabs should be, thats my suggestion I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I solved it by the following code in onCreate method

```
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_frame_layout);
    frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    final FloatingActionsMenu fabMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);
    fabMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(130);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    fabMenu.collapse();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            frameLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
            frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
    });
```